# How can you get the source text from an essential graphics property that is not a text layer?

Tags: adobe, extendscript, after-effects

I'm looking to make a *very* simple script. I just want to take a layer with a source text essential graphics property, and rename the layer to what that source text's value currently is.

Here's the relevant code, it loops over all the selected layers and *should* access the property of the layer and rename it to what the source text property's value is.

```
  for(var i = 0; i < curComp.selectedLayers.length; i++) {
    var currLayer = curComp.selectedLayers[i];
    var sourceTextProp = currLayer.sourceText;
    var name = sourceTextProp.value;
    try{
      currLayer.name = name;
    }catch(error) {
      $.writeln('this layer has no source');
    }
    currLayer.name = name;
  }
```

The `var sourceTextProp = currLayer.sourceText; var name = sourceTextProp.value;` is notably giving me issues. I've tried treating it like a text layer, tried here to use a property object, all to no avail. I have no clue what to do and no tutorials online seem to spell this out well.

Is there a way to search through an object and find properties of a certain type? Like search for "source text" and have the script locate the value? This feels like something I should be able to do.

The critical issue here is just not being able to access the source text's value. I can rename layers just fine with this script if I just feed it a string.

Any help would be loads appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A text layer's `sourceText` property is a [textDocument](https://ae-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/other/textdocument/#textdocument-object) object, not, as you might expect, a string. You can access its text by using

```
var name = sourceTextProp.value.text;
```